# Adobe ColdFusion not installing

Tags: coldfusion

Hello I am working on installing ColdFusion on my Windows 10 PC. But when I get to the part where I specify the server port number, it says

```
Port is not valid or available. Please change the port.
```

It does this no matter what I put in for the port number.

Any ideas on what is the matter?

UPDATE:

It turns out this was an issue with other software on my computer.  Removing that fixed the issue.

Comment: Not related to ColdFusion, but Windows. Start here: http://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-a-windows-machine

Comment: Maybe Skype is taking over port 80. If that's the case, google how to configure Skype to not use port 80.

Comment: What screen do you enter that? Can you not go with the default path, already specified there?

Comment: @AnitKumar It is the screen right after you select "use built in server".  It asks you for a port number.  The default doesn't work or any of the ones I have tried.

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: What are the port numbers you have tried?

Comment: Can you try VIPER's step mentioned in the "ANSWER" below?

Answer (score 2):

```
Port is not valid or available. Please change the port.
```

This error probably occurs when the port number is pre-occupied by some other application

You can possibly try changing to a port number that is available

Or try finding and killing the process that is listening to that port this can be established by cmd command

```
netstat -a
```

or

```
netstat -a -n
```

-n will speed it up as it skips host name resolution
Hope this helps